# Generic implementation of interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Why isn't this working ?

```
public interface IPoint
{
  // not important
}

public interface IPointList
{
  List<IPoint> Points { get; }
}

public abstract class Point : IPoint
{
  // implemented IPoint
}

public abstract class PointList<TPointType> : IPointList
  where TPointType: IPoint
{
  public abstract List<TPointType> Points { get; } // <- doesn't compile
}
```

The TPointType obviously has to be an IPoint. Why this implementation is not allowed ?

regards,
Kate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an answer to your comment, on how to get best of both worlds; 
I was thinking of something like this, where you implement your interface GetPoints property explictily, create a GetPoints property that is 'more typed', and an protected abstract method that you can override in concrete implementations.
The 2 properties call the abstract implementation.

```
    public abstract class PointList<T> : IPointList where T : IPoint
    {
        public IList<T> GetPoints
        {
            get
            {
                return GetPointsCore ();
            }
        }

        IList<IPoint> IPointList.GetPoints
        {
            get
            {
                return GetPointsCore () as IList<IPoint>;
            }        
        }

        protected abstract IList<T> GetPointsCore();        
    }
```

Comment: Elegant. Thanks that is exactly what I was after and it works like a charm.

Comment: This could would always return null when used like this: { PointList<Point> list = new PointList<Point>(); var x = ((IPointList)list).GetPoints; } in this case x will be null because IList<Point> cannot be cast to an IList<IPoint> (at least not until C# 4.0 in VS 2010).

Comment: Now that I think about it, this wouldn't work in C# 4.0 either because an IList is not covariant.

Answer (score 2):

The class PointList *should* implement the IPointList interface. Methods/properties cannot differ by return type only, which is what you're trying to do with the Points declaration in class PointList. If you implement

```
List<TPointType> Points { get; }
```

then logically you cannot implement

```
List<IPoint> Points { get; }
```

Because they would differ by return type only.

Comment: Ok. So the interface - as far as types are concerned - has to be as it is. Is there any way how to have the best of both worlds. So descendants can have generics and also the interface is satisfied ? Because this way I've to have Points and also some other property List<TPointType> GenericPoints ?

Comment: In my case the generic interfaces are a road to hell. I tried that first I ended up with six parameters long interfaces. This example is not what I'm really trying to implemented (which several multitudes more complex). Thx for the comment thou.